# Collection Testing with Vows.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vows

I am trying to run unit tests against every item in a collection using Vows.js and I'm having a heck of a time getting it to work. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
'the variations objects': {
  topic: function() {
    var promise = new(events.EventEmitter),
      variations = JSON.parse(body).variations;

    for(var i = variations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      promise.emit("success", variations[i]);
    };

    return promise;
  },
  'should have an x': function(topic) {
    should.exist(topic.x);
  },
  'should have an action on the add_to_cart object if the product is IN_STOCK': function(topic) {
    if(topic.x.id === 'TEST'){
      should.exist(topic.x.action)
    }
  }
}
```

This seems like it is working. However, when I run the tests, I get 34 passed and 1 error. Vows does not indicate what test is erroring. I don't feel like using an `EventEmitter` is the right choice for this, but I'm not sure how else to have a new topic for each object in a given collection.